# BoxLayout misunderstanding strut

Tags: java, swing, boxlayout

I'm prgramming a simple input diagram in Swing. I use boxLayout to create a simple GUI of user input. Problem is that creating a horizontal strut between the JPanel of all the labels and the JPanel of the JTextFields causes the whole panel to shift downwards (weird) this is the whole panel:

```
private JPanel secondCard() {

    //main panel. set the boxlayout
    secondCard = new JPanel();
    secondCard.setLayout(new BoxLayout(secondCard,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    // create vertical strut for looks
    secondCard.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));

    // create title. center it.
    JLabel title = new JLabel("Configure main network parameters "); 
    title.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    secondCard.add(title);

    // create vertical strut for looks
    secondCard.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));

    // create panel for the description labels
    JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
    labelPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labelPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    labelPanel.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    JLabel inPut =new JLabel("number of inputs");
    inPut.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    labelPanel.add(inPut);

    inPut =new JLabel("number of outputs");
    inPut.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    labelPanel.add(inPut);

    inPut =new JLabel("number of layers");
    inPut.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    labelPanel.add(inPut);

    JPanel textFieldPanel = new JPanel();
    textFieldPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(textFieldPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    textFieldPanel.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    JTextField inputTextField = new JTextField();
    inputTextField.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    textFieldPanel.add(inputTextField);
    inputTextField.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0,0));

    inputTextField = new JTextField();
    inputTextField.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    textFieldPanel.add(inputTextField);
    inputTextField.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0,0));

    inputTextField = new JTextField();
    inputTextField.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    textFieldPanel.add(inputTextField);
    inputTextField.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0,0));

    textFieldPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(50, labelPanel.getMaximumSize().height));

    JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
    inputPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(inputPanel,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    inputPanel.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    inputPanel.add(labelPanel);

    //this is the problem strut!! it causes inputPanel to shift downwards 
    inputPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));

    inputPanel.add(textFieldPanel);

    secondCard.add(inputPanel);

    return secondCard;
}
```

without the strut it looks like:
[image]

With strut it looks like (I know I suck at picture editing):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You are adding a `Box` strut to a `BoxLayout`.

As the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html#createHorizontalStrut%28int%29) states, `createHorizontalStrut(int width)`:

> Creates an invisible, fixed-width component. In a horizontal box, you
>   typically use this method to force a certain amount of space between
>   two components. In a vertical box, you might use this method to force
>   the box to be at least the specified width. The invisible component
>   has no height unless excess space is available, in which case it takes
>   its share of available space, just like any other component that has
>   no maximum height.

As such, it is filling the height between your title `JLabel` and the bottom of the `JPanel`.

You might want to consider using `Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20, height))` instead, where height could be specified or set to the height of `labelPanel`.

Or, you could reconsider the layout for your `JPanel` - take a look at the [visual guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

For future reference, if you cannot make sense of your Swing layout, try putting adding a coloured `LineBorder` to the `JComponent`s you're unsure of. In this case, the `Box` struts are not `JComponent`s but `Component`s, so you'd have to put them into a `JPanel`, but this would at least have shown you what space each component was taking up in your top-level `JPanel`.

Comment: [`javax.swing.Box`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#filler) is "A lightweight container that uses a BoxLayout object as its layout manager." `Box.Filler` is a static nested class that works quite well with `Box` or `BoxLayout`.

Answer (score 3):

- use [Cardlayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for wizard logics
- put [JLabel(Configure ...., JLabel.CENTER)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) to the `BorderLayout.NORTH`
- put [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) with [JButtons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#jbutton) to the BorderLayout.SOUTH
- put JPanel with [SpringLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html), [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html), or [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`
- [Top-Level Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) have got implemened [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) by default, then there no reason to re_define `BorderLayout`
- above mentioned steps are called `NestedLayout`
- alternative are put all `JComponents` by using `GridBagLayout`, `SpringLayout` or todays `MigLayout` to the one `JPanel`, but why bothering

Comment: I placed the buttonPanel ("previous","next","finish" & "cancel") at contentPane.SOUTH. in the centre of the contentPane I placed a JPanel with cardlayout. The secondCard JPanel is the code shown above. It is the second card of the layout (poor nomenclature, I know). Is that a good aproach? I chose BoxLayout because it is simple and because BorderLayout sucks

Comment: @user1111: BorderLayout can work well, especially if used in conjunction with other layouts as mKorbel recommends. 1+ to mKorbel.

Answer (score 2):

Example of a nested layout, one using BorderLayout, FlowLayout (JPanel's default), and GridBagLayout:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.*;

public class LayoutFoo {
   private static final String TITLE = "Configure Main Foobar Parameters";
   private static final String[] LABEL_TEXTS = {
      "Number of Spams", "Number of Frapzats", "Number of Zignuts"
   };
   private static final int TEXTFIELD_SIZE = 10;
   private static final Insets WEST_INSETS = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 10);
   private static final Insets EAST_INSETS = new Insets(5, 10, 5, 5);
   private static final int EB_GAP = 5;
   private Map<String, JTextField> textFieldMap = new HashMap<String, JTextField>();

   public JPanel getConfigFooPanel() {
      JPanel textFieldPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
      for (int i = 0; i < LABEL_TEXTS.length; i++) {
         addTextAndField(textFieldPanel, LABEL_TEXTS[i], i);
      }

      int blVertGap = 20;
      JPanel borderLayoutPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, blVertGap));
      borderLayoutPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(EB_GAP, EB_GAP,
            EB_GAP, EB_GAP));
      JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel(TITLE, JLabel.CENTER);
      borderLayoutPanel.add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      borderLayoutPanel.add(textFieldPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      JPanel outerWrapperFlowPanel = new JPanel();
      outerWrapperFlowPanel.add(borderLayoutPanel);

      return outerWrapperFlowPanel;      
   }

   public String getFieldText(String labelText) {
      JTextField field = textFieldMap.get(labelText);
      if (field == null) {
         return ""; // ?? throw exception
      } else {
         return field.getText();
      }
   }

   private void addTextAndField(JPanel panel, String text, int i) {
      JLabel label = new JLabel(text, JLabel.LEFT);
      JTextField textField = new JTextField(TEXTFIELD_SIZE);
      textFieldMap.put(text, textField);
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = i;
      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
      gbc.insets = WEST_INSETS;
      panel.add(label, gbc);

      gbc.gridx = 1;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
      gbc.insets = EAST_INSETS;
      panel.add(textField, gbc);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("LayoutFoo");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new LayoutFoo().getConfigFooPanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```